# getting problem for updating my tableview value to detail lable section

Tags: iphone, tableview

My application is navigation base , I have two Table ViewControllers ,I am selecting data from second tableview and updating to details label of first tabaleview. The following code i am tried but not updating , I am getting secondtableview value in "Updatetableviewlable" method but i am not updating "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method, where i am doing mistake .. please any one guide me .

```
     @class First;

            @interface FertilityAppAppDelegate 


                First *firstObj;

            @property (nonatomic,retain) First *firstObj;

            @implementation FertilityAppAppDelegate
            @synthesize firstObj;


> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions


 //code 1
//  Updating detail view from second tableview to first tableview .


        firstObj= [[First alloc] initWithNibName:  @"First" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]   initWithRootViewController: firstObj];
        self.navigationController = aNavigationController;
        [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
 //code 2
// Not Updating detail view from second tableview to first tableview

      mainmenuObj = [[Mainmenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"Mainmenu" bundle:nil];
        firstObj= [[First alloc] initWithNibName:  @"First" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]   initWithRootViewController: mainmenuObj];
        self.navigationController = aNavigationController;
        [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;         


        @interface First 
                 NSString *symptomlabel; FertilityAppAppDelegate *Appdelegate;
         @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *symptomlabel    
        @implementation First
            @synthesize symptomlabel;


            - (void)viewDidLoad
            { 
                Appdelegate = (FertilityAppAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


            }

            -(void) Updatetableviewlable:(NSString*)lable
            {
                symptomlabel=[lable retain] ;
                NSLog(@"the update value is  %@", lable);


            }
            - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
    *)indexPath 
        {
            static NSString *cellId = @"CellId";

            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
            if (cell == nil) 
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellId] autorelease];
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;   
            }
            switch (indexPath.section) 
            {
                case 0:
                {   
                    cell.textLabel.text = [self.MenstruationtoWakingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                    if(indexPath.row==0)
                    {
                        UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 25, 125, 15)];
                        myLabel.text =symptomlabel;
                        myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                        myLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
                        [self.tableView addSubview:myLabel];
                        NSLog(@"The Save file is:%@",symptomlabel);


                    }                    
                //statement case upto 10        
                }
        }           
        }
            @interface Second : UITableViewController 

            {


                FertilityAppAppDelegate *appDelegate;
            }


             @implementation Second tableview

                                viewDidLoad 

                                appDelegate = (FertilityAppAppDelegate
    *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


            - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
    *)indexPath
            {
             if(indexPath.section==0)
             {     
              if (indexPath.row==0)
              {       
                NSString *updatelable =@"None";
                [appDelegate.firstObj Updatetableviewlable:updatelable];
                 appDelegate.selectedRow =indexPath.row;
              }
              //statement upto row 5

             }
                [self.tableView reloadData]; 
            }
```

Comment: @simon I have one doubts about this question , My First Table view if i call didFinishLaunchingWithOptions through initWithRootViewController i can able to update my detail view from second table view to first table view. But  if i call Mainmanu class to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as post code i am not able to update my detail view , Why?

Comment: Sorry man.. I can't get your question.. Can you explain, what you want to do, step by step?

Comment: Mainmenu UIViewController is main window of my application . Itself button event. click on button open to FirstTableView. If click on cell of first tableview open to Second TableView. according to seconding tableview cell selection value , updating to First TableView , Detailview section . See My edited question of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and i using code 2 It is not updating .see link 
http://www.ziddu.com/download/13578496/Updatetable.zip.html

Comment: @SOF: Give me some time. I am looking into your code.

Comment: Your code has following issues: **1.** You created a **firstObj** at two places. One in your **appDelegate**, another one in your **Mainmenu**. In your **Mainmenu**, you are creating new **firstObj** and pushing it to the **navigation controller**. You are supposed to push the **firstObj** which is in **appDelegate**.

Comment: **2.**In your **First** class, you are releasing **appDelegate**. You should not release **appDelegate**, and also you created a @propert declaration for **appDelegate**, that is also is not necessary.

Comment: Replace the following code with the one in your **Mainmenu**. -(IBAction)firstbuttonpressed:(id)sender
{
 appDelegate = (FertilityAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:appDelegate.firstObj animated:YES];

}

Comment: These changes should fix your problem. Post me if any problem.

Comment: @SOF: Thanks for  your acknowledgment. I am also a kinda newbie developer. I also had these problems. That's why I take pleasure to help other newbie developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Updatetableviewlable:` method, you are assigning `lable` to `symptomlabel`. In this case, the `symptomlabel` may not retain the string `lable`. You try having `Updatetableviewlable:` method like this.

```
- (void)Updatetableviewlable:(NSString*)lable {

    symptomlabel = [lable retain];
    NSLog(@"%@", symptomlabel);
}
```

And make sure your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method looks something like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...

    UILabel *myLabel;

    if (cell == nil) {

        myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 25, 125, 15)];
        myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        myLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        myLabel.text = symptomlabel;
        [myLabel setTag:1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel];
        [myLabel release];

    } else {

        myLabel = [[cell contentView] viewWithTag:1];
        myLabel.text = symptomlabel;
    }

    ...
}
```

Add also make sure you are reloading the table view in `viewWillAppear:` method of your `First.m`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 

    [[self tableView] reloadData]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do an reload data on your table view. This will call again your cellForRowAtIndexPath.

In your setter add `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Edit:

1 . You have to release your label.

2 . Other problem you can add many labels to your cells when you are reusing it. Dest you subclass UITableViewCell and do your custom layout there. This will improve scroll performance on slow devices like iPhone 3G. Try in your cellForRowAtIndexPath not to alloc and init objects and not to do computing code (for(), while()). This will improve your scroll performance very much.

Edit 2:

You must set on your property (copy) or (retain) `@property (nonatomic,retain)   NSString *symptomlabel;`